# How to rotate Shape which is aggregation of rotated individual parts?

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, lwjgl, jogl

My drawing which is again aggregation of small lines or circle which i am rotating (mostly lines) at various angels.
Now I want to rotate this entire drawing to certain angel.

[image]

You can see what i want to achieve.
So my question is about how can i rotate entire drawing.

```
@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
    final GL2 gl = arg0.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   
    drwaMan(gl);
    gl.glFlush();
   
}

private void drwaMan(GL2 gl) {
    // this line is not working i was hoping by doing something like this entire shape will rotate
    //gl.glRotatef(15, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
    
    float radius = 50;
    float cx = 100, cy = 400; // center of circle
    int bodyAngel = 180; // draw line at angel
    float bodyLineLength = 150;
    int lineAngel = 270;

    // calculate first point of line 
    float px = (float) (radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(bodyAngel))) + cx;
    float py = (float) (radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(bodyAngel))) + cy;
    
    // draw head
    drawCircle(gl,radius,cx,cy);
    // draw line
    drawBoadyLine(gl,px,py,bodyLineLength,lineAngel);
    
    // drawhands 50 distance from starting point
    drawHands(gl,px,py-50,225,315,100);
    
    // lags at end of line
    drawHands(gl,px,py-150,225,315,100);
}

void drawCircle(GL2 gl,float radius,float cx,float cy)
{
   gl.glLoadIdentity();
   gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
   gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
 
   for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
            float x1, y1;
            x1 = (float) (radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i))) + cx;
            y1 = (float) (radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i))) + cy;
            gl.glVertex2d(x1,y1);
    }
 
   gl.glEnd();
}
private void drawHands(GL2 gl, float x, float y, int a1, int a2,int l) {

    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(a1, 0, 0, 1);
    
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
        gl.glVertex2f(0, 0);
        gl.glVertex2f(l, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
    
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(a2, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
        gl.glVertex2f(0, 0);
        gl.glVertex2f(l, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
}

private void drawBoadyLine(GL2 gl, float x, float y, float bodyLineLength, int bodyAngel) {
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(bodyAngel, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
    
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
        gl.glVertex2f(0, 0);
        gl.glVertex2f(bodyLineLength, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
    
}
```

I appreciate if you guys provide some solution or any help pointing to related martial which address this issue with some example is helpful.

**Note:** I have used OpenGL - JOGL binding to write is code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a 2D transformation to me. I've found [this page helpful](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm) as a kind of cheat sheet for transformations.

Comment: @dbrown93 This article is only about theoretical knowledge no real examples about how can that be achieve by any api's.

Comment: Yes but it would simply be applying the part about rotations about a point. So you would translate the "center" of the man to the origin, rotate the coordinates, and translate the man back

Comment: You should do something [similar](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/helloTriangle/HelloTriangle.java#L275-L278)

Answer (score 0):

The first statement of `drawCircle` is:

```
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

That will reset current transformation matrix to identity.

That make the `gl.glRotatef(15, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);` call useless.

You should remove all those calls to `glLoadIdentity` and do it only once after `glClear` in the `display` function.

You should also take a look on:

- [glMatrixMode](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) To know witch matrix is impacted.
- [glPush/glPop](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) That allow you to do temporary transformation (for parts of an object).

Comment: by removing that entire shape becomes disconnected and shapes are drawn at random location

Comment: Maybe, but you can uncomment the glRotate command and see that the 'random' image rotate. Actually, there is nothing random, and you have to think further on where you want transformation (like joint) and where your coordinate have to be static. It's take time to master base changing.